# Is there a reason to use __proto__ instead of setPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm reading the source code of `express 4`, which is pretty new, and there is the following code there:

```
var proto = module.exports = function(options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  function router(req, res, next) {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  }

  // mixin Router class functions
  router.__proto__ = proto;
         ^^^^^^^^^

  router.params = {};
  router._params = [];
  router.caseSensitive = opts.caseSensitive;
  router.mergeParams = opts.mergeParams;
  router.strict = opts.strict;
  router.stack = [];

  return router;
};
```

I'm wondering if there is any reason why they used `__proto__` instead of `setPrototypeOf`, except the ability to run express on JS engine earlier than ECMAScript 5.1 (ECMA-262)?

Comment: The only reason is they might think it improves performance. In most cases, I would avoid setting it directly unless it's the last option.

Comment: nice warning signs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Are you sure this code is new? It looks like express always did.

Comment: @Bergi, the framework version (v4) seems to be new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of legacy support issue. See: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2613

Comment: Oh really? I thought the proper way to support legacy environments is by shimming instead of using deprecated things in the entire codebase.

Comment: Well, shimming in this case would still require using  `__proto__` for legacy browsers. One way or the other, there's no avoiding it.